# mutt/neomutt - color of 'active' message in index menu

Tags: colors, mutt

The mutt documentation (http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#color) lists a bunch of color objects than can be modified:

`color object foreground background`

However none of these color objects (I tried every single one in my `.muttrc`) seem to change the foreground and background color of the 'active' message in the index menu (the selected message, which changes when pressing the up and down keys). By default this message has a green foreground and a black background as far as I can tell. I would like to set colors such that the 'active' message has a non-black background, like in this screenshot I found somewhere, where the background of the 'active' message is red: https://hobosource.files.wordpress.com/2016/08/neomutt-view.png

Comment: `color indicator fg bg`...

Comment: I feel so stupid... changing the `indicator` object had no effect, and I finally discovered why - I sourced another file in my muttrc with the sidebar configuration in it (and some color configurations as well), which overwrote the indicator configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In documentation you've [linked](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#color):

```
Usage:

color object foreground background 
...
object can be one of:
...
indicator (arrow or bar used to indicate the current item in a menu)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I modified the indicator object but it had no effect, but it's all solved now - see above comment.